# let $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) =L \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) =0 \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: limits

let $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) =L \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) =0 $ :

then :

$$\lim _{x \to a } \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}= ?$$

when Is equal to $ -\infty $ ?

when Is equal to $ +\infty $ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) =0$?

Comment: @sharding4 I edited . thank you .

Comment: To distinguish $-\infty$ and $\infty$ look at the sign of the numerator and compare that with the various possibilities for the sign of the denominator.

Comment: It  is not necessarily defined, for example, $f(x) = L$, $g(x) = x-a$. depending on how you approach zero, you can get $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by @copper.hat -you don't know that it is either $\pm \infty$ unfortunately! For example take $f(x)=1$ constant; and $g(x) = x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$, and $a=0$. So $g(x) \to 0$ and $f(x) \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. However the sign of $g(x)$ changes infinitely often as $x \to 0$ so we can't say that we tend to $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if $L\neq0$ then it is
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L\cdot\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{g(x)}
$$
where the product is intended in the extended real number line. 
The remaining limit is $+\infty$ if $g(x)$ is positive in a neighborhood of $a$, and $-\infty$ if $g(x)$ is negative in a neighborhood of $a$.
For the whole limit also the sign of $L$ should be taken into account.

For one side limit, the sign of $g(x)$ should be checked in a one side neighborhood.

Comment: You can't break up the limit if you don't know whether the limit of $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ exists, which we don't

Comment: thanks . if $a = \pm \infty $ now what?

Comment: @SEWillB: you can if you agree that $L\cdot \text{undef}=\text{undef}$

Comment: @Almot1960: the fact that $a$ is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ does not change nothing, but the fact that there is only a one side limit.